# Autocomplete for TinyMCE v4

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, tinymce, jquery-autocomplete, tinymce-4

I just started using TinyMCE v4 for my blog site. I want to add an auto-complete/tagging feature similar to Facebook where you start typing someones name and a list comes out with peoples name for you to select. Upon selecting a user, it would insert a link tag to their profile. Something like `<a href="/link/to/profile" uid="user-id">John Doe</a>`.

If there is a plugin that already does this and I just have to provide a list then that would be awesome! Otherwise, here is what I need to know:

1) Capture each key typed so I can generate a pull down list on the fly. Any suggestions on this would be good like how to throttle the results so it's not annoying for the user to type anything without a flyout menu coming up every second.

2) I'll create my own ajax response page that will send back a list of matching users and I think I can just generate a list for them to tab through. Shouldn't be that hard but if anyone has any suggestions on something like this already done in TinyMCE then please share :)

3) Upon selecting the user from the list in #2, I need to insert a link to the user profile and add the "uid" parameter. This should be where the cursor is currently at in tinymce.

I think that should cover it! I'm using version 4 of TinyMCE.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Realize you may have found an answer by now, but thought I'd share this plugin. I think it's fantastic-- the only thing it leaves me wanting is the ability to render some sort of loading symbol for when there is a lag getting the source over ajax.

https://github.com/CogniStreamer/tinyMCE-mention